# Log4j - STMPAppender NoSuchProviderException stmp

Tags: java, error-handling, log4j, smtpappender

I'm trying to send errors of my GWT project with log4j but i'm having a problem.
This is what I've added to the log4j.xml file:

```
<appender name="EMAIL" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">
<param name="BufferSize" value="512" />
<param name="SMTPHost" value="localhost" />
<param name="From" value="myemail@teste.com" />
<param name="To" value="myemail@teste.com" />
<param name="Subject" value="[SMTPAppender] Application message" />
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%p %d (%c{1}) %m%n" />
</layout>
<filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
    <param name="LevelMin" value="ERROR" />
    <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL" />
</filter>
</appender>

<root>
<level value="WARN" />
<appender-ref ref="EMAIL" />
</root>
```

Simple but it gives me the following error when trying to send a email?

```
log4j:ERROR Error occured while sending e-mail notification.
javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: smtp
at javax.mail.Session.getService(Session.java:806)
at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:728)
at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:668)
at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:648)
at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:705)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:192)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender.sendBuffer(SMTPAppender.java:330)
at org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender.append(SMTPAppender.java:215)
at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.error(Category.java:305)
at pt.keep.vault.web.server.WebServiceImpl.login(WebServiceImpl.java:1257)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

I've already added activation-1.1.jar and mail.jar (1.4.6 API) to my project.
What could be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure your jar are in your war ?

Comment: The .jar files are in war/WEB-INF/lib/... What could be wrong?

Comment: Yes' I think you have theses jar in another path and jetty take them in first. Try to locate  them., especialy mail.jar (mail-1.3.....jar in example)

Comment: Related to the error stack is [Bug 6668 -skip unusable Store and Transport classes](https://kenai.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6668) which is fixed in JavaMail 1.5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration - it works for me and it uses gmail as smtp server which may be good option for you in both development and production environment. I use log4j version: 1.2.16 and apache-log4j-extras version 1.0 (this extra lib is neccessary only if you use: `FilterBasedTriggeringPolicy`)

```
<appender name="emailApp" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">
    <param name="SMTPProtocol" value="smtps" /> 
    <param name="SMTPHost" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <param name="SMTPPort" value="465" />
    <param name="SMTPUsername" value="your.gmail.username" />
    <param name="SMTPPassword" value="xxxxx" />
    <param name="From" value="your.gmail.username@gmail.com" />
    <param name="To" value="target@devnull.com" />
    <param name="Subject" value="Logging from my application" />
    <param name="BufferSize" value="1" />
    <triggeringPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.FilterBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="WARN"/>
            <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL"/>
        </filter>
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS} %-4r %-5p %c %x - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: Stills gives the same error.
The .jar files are in war/WEB-INF/lib/...
What could be wrong?

Comment: Yes, jars should be in WEB-INF/lib directory

Comment: After deploying to tomcat it's working. With GWT development environment it doesn't work, but that's not a problem.
The problem is that I can't put it work with SMTPS, because it doesn't reconize the tags STMPProtocol and SMTPHost.

Comment: Are you sure that you use correct library version? SSL using smtps is supported since version 1.2.16.